# How to retrieve the most recent object in an array prior to a given date?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple, unsorted array of objects:

```
const items = [
  { item: 'Two', date: '2018-01-01' },
  { item: 'Three', date: '2019-01-01' },
  { item: 'One', date: '2022-01-01' },
  { item: 'Four', date: '2021-01-01' },
];
```

I am trying to build a function that takes a single `effDate` parameter and returns the most recent `item` whose `date` property is prior to the `effDate`.

For example, if I pass `2020-08-22` as the parameter, the function would return item `Three`, since it is the closest to the `effDate` without going over.

I have tried to use a reducer, but I am sure I am doing this wrong, since it always returns the first object in the array:

```
const getItem = (effDate) => {
  return items.reduce((prev, next) => {
    return next.date > prev.date && next.date < effDate.date
    ? next
    : prev;
  });
};
```

So, without building an entire looping / comparison function myself, is this possible with the built-in JS tools?

Comment: Sort the array in reverse by date. Then use `find()` to find the first element before `effData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barmar said in comments:

> Sort the array in reverse by date. Then use find() to find the first
> element before effData.

1. [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) date in descending order
2. [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the nearest to the date effDate

```js
const items = [{ item: 'Two', date: '2018-01-01' }, { item: 'Three', date: '2019-01-01' }, { item: 'One', date: '2022-01-01' }, { item: 'Four', date: '2021-01-01' }, ];
const getItem = (effDate) => {
  //1.
  let itemsSorted = items.slice().sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date))
  //2. 
  return itemsSorted.find(item => Date.parse(item.date) < Date.parse(effDate));
};
console.log(getItem('2020-08-22'));
```